# Java11 + Springboot-2.1.5.RELEASE memory leaks

Tags: spring-boot, memory-management, memory-leaks, java-11

- My stack is Java11 + Springboot-2.1.5.RELEASE.
- I have download heapdump and analyzed the memory leaks and found the following suspect.

Could anybody help me to resolve the following issue? Quick help appreciated, thanks in advance.

[image: Springboot memory leaks]

[image: Memory wastage]

Comment: What make you think it's a leak vs normal memory usage ?

Comment: @benbenw: According to analysis report it has been notified as a problem suspect. I am bit confused about this. Could you please confirm it is not a memory leak.? Thank you :)

Comment: Here Eclipse MAT is reporting the 'dominator' tree, it's a 'suspect' as it uses a large part of the memory. But it may be a normal behaviour of your application. A leak implies that the memory usage always increase.